# I want to change matplotlib pyplot font at 'matplotlibrc font.family' .But the only thing that came back was 'font.family: command not found'

Tags: matplotlib, fonts, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

[image]

I installed a new font because of the broken letters like the picture above.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install fonts-nanum*
```

And I downloaded the font after the update. And I removed the cache.

```
$ sudo fc-cache -fv
```

Then You can see the font 'nanum' installed in the next picture.

[image]

Copy 'nanum' font to matplotlib and delete font cache of matplotlib

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/fonts/truetype/nanum/Nanum* /home/hy1/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/

$ rm -rf /home/hy1/.cache/matplotlib/*
```

[image]

[image]

I checked whether the 'nanum' font is available for 'matplotlib' in 'jupyter notebook'. A list of available 'nanum' fonts has been printed as shown in the next picture.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.font_manager


[(f.name, f.fname) for f in fm.fontManager.ttflist if 'Nanum' in f.name]
```

[image]

Finally, it does not apply in the process of going to 'matplotlibrc' and modifying font-family with vim.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The matplotlibrc is not a .bashrc file. You don't need to `source` it (the error message is from your shell, not from a python process/matplotlib). The next time you import matplotlib, that matplotlibrc file should be loaded automatically, if it is in the right location, etc.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen oh thanks a lot. As advised, I ran 'anaconda' again and the font was automatically applied.